# put a hyperlink on table data when using with echo

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, hyperlink

I am using the following code to display data in the form a table

```
echo "<table id='admin'>
<tr>
<th>ID</th>
<th> Name </th>
th>Email</th>
<th>Headline</th>
</tr>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
{
echo "<tr>" ;
echo "<td>" . $row['id'] ."</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['email'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['headline'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
```

I have found many similar question but they mostly displayed hyperlink along with simple echo and their solution didn't work for me. I want that what ever data gets printed in this line i.e `echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";` should also behave as a hyperlink and redirect to another page. i tried to insert href link after  but it showed syntax error. Any help would be appreciated
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo "<td><a href='link'>" . $row['name'] . "</a></td>";
```

Answer (score 2):

Like This

```
echo "<table id='admin'>
<tr>
<th>ID</th>
<th> Name </th>
th>Email</th>
<th>Headline</th>
</tr>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
{
echo "<tr>" ;
echo "<td><a href='#'>" . $row['id'] ."</a></td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['email'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['headline'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "<td><a href='other.php'>" . $row['name'] . "</a></td>";
```

And also,

```
th>Email</th>
```

replace this with

```
<th>Email</th>
```